# Preserve The Scroll Position After Option (Onclick)

Tags: javascript, php

I have a MAIN page with content from other page.

```
create_table_paging($query,$table,$pages,$row_query,$pageNum);
```

Forms are generated dynamically using the database to update. I need to keep the scroll to go to the same place where it was when I select the option from drop down list. I know I have to use scrollTo(x,y) I have been trying but nothings works... Can anyone post a snippet showing how to capture the coordinates.

```
<option value=\"1\" ".$proceed." onClick=\"window.location='index.php?pages=job&job_id=".$row->job_refno."';\">Pro‌​ceed</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

Get **offsetTop** value of element and scroll:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetTop

Comment: can explain more about offsetTop. i have see the link but not fully understand and how to apply it.